# Analysis. Limits of real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Compute the limit of
$$a_n =\frac{7^n + n^{3}4^n}{n^{10} − 7^n}$$

I have written this as $$\frac{1}{\frac{n^{10}}{7^n}-1} + \frac{4^n}{n^7 -\frac{7^n}{n^3}}$$

I know the limit of the first fraction is $-1$ and I tried to use the growth factor test to prove this but it is not getting me somewhere so I do not know what method to use.

Comment: I take it you mean "as n goes to infinity".  I would divide both numerator and denominator by 7^n since that is the fastest growing term.  That gives an= (1+ (n^34^n)/7^n)/(n^10/7^n- 1).  Every term with 7^n in the denominator goes to 0 so the limit is 1/(-1)= -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1+\dfrac{n^3}{\left(\dfrac74\right)^n}}{\dfrac{n^{10}}{7^n}-1}=\dfrac{1+0}{0-1}$$

Apply L'hospital $m$ times in $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^m}{a^n}=\frac{m!}{(\ln a)^m a^n}=0$$ for $a>1$ for finite $m$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Factor out the dominant term $7^n$ from numerator and denominator to obtain

$$\frac {1+\frac{n^3}{\left(\frac74\right)^n}}{\frac{n^{10}}{7^n}-1}$$

and recall that for any $a>1$

$$\frac{n^k} {a^n}\to 0$$

Comment: it is n^10 not 10^n though

Comment: Yes already fixed indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{1-\frac{n^3\times 4^n}{7^n}}{\frac{n^{10}}{7^n}-1}$$

Comment: it is n^10 not 10^n though